# Where is UWP MapControl antialiasing property?

Tags: c#, uwp, antialiasing, uwp-maps

I work with `UWP MapControl` and adding some `MapPolylines`.
And they looks ugly (see pic below)
[image]

I assume should be kind of `antialiasing` property but cannot find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol?view=winrt-20348).

Please help and thank you!

**C#**

```
var mapPolyline = new MapPolyline();
var geoPositions = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
foreach (var vertex in polyLine.Vertex)
{
  // adding BasicGeopositions...
};
mapPolyline.StrokeColor = Colors.Black;
mapPolyline.StrokeThickness = 1;
mapPolyline.Path = new Geopath(geoPositions);
((MapElementsLayer)impotMapLayer).MapElements.Add(mapPolyline);
```

**UPDATE #1 based on the answer**

I have investigated this article  ["Overlay tiled images on a map"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images) and also
this one `"MapTileBitmapRequestedEventArgs Class"` and cannot get the clear definition of the X and Y of `"MapTileBitmapRequestedEventArgs Class"`

The article says

```
X   Gets the X value of the requested tile.
Y   Gets the Y value of the requested tile.
```

Using MSDN example from [here](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images)  I get following log for **X, Y, Zoom**

```
X 6073  Y 2617 Zoom 13
X 6072  Y 2616 Zoom 13
X 6071  Y 2615 Zoom 13
X 6071  Y 2617 Zoom 13
X 6072  Y 2614 Zoom 13
X 6073  Y 2615 Zoom 13
X 6071  Y 2616 Zoom 13
X 6073  Y 2614 Zoom 13
X 6072  Y 2615 Zoom 13
    
    and etc
```

Would you mind clarify what those numbers are exactly and how I can associate it with geolocations set of vertices in memory if I want create tile-image only, please?
(My polylines set already calculated in geopoints.)

Thank you very much!

UPDATE #2 Here is the solution

First of all I read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/bing-maps-tile-system?redirectedfrom=MSDN

So we need `TileSystem` to make series of convertions

```
namespace Microsoft.MapPoint 
{  
    static class TileSystem  
...
```

The **X** and **Y** of `MapTileBitmapRequestedEventArgs`  are **Tile's XY** we have to pass to `TileSystem.TileXYToPixelXY(args.X, args.Y, out int pixelX, out int pixelY);`

The final code is following based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images

```
private async void customDataSource_BitmapRequestedAsync(CustomMapTileDataSource sender, MapTileBitmapRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
             
            
    TileSystem.TileXYToPixelXY(args.X, args.Y, out int pixelX, out int pixelY);
                    
    TileSystem.PixelXYToLatLong(pixelX, pixelY,  args.ZoomLevel, out double  lat, out double lng);
    
    Debug.WriteLine($"lat {lat}  lng {lng} Zoom {args.ZoomLevel}");
    
    // next step is to extract from my custom array polylines accroding to   TileSystem.PixelXYToLatLong

    // and finally pass it inside of CreateBitmapAsStreamAsync(array to draw);
    
    args.Request.PixelData = await CreateBitmapAsStreamAsync(array to draw);
                         
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently MapPolylines are drawn without antialiasing and there is no setting to change that behavior.
Looking at your screenshot, you may be better served by using a custom tile layer. See CustoMapTileDatasource here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images
You can draw each tile in a callback using whatever method you like including antialiasing. It will also tend to perform better for a large collection of static lines like the topographic contours in your example